# Scala type mismatch: found Future[MyType] required Future[Option[MyType]]

Tags: scala

I'm getting a `Future[MyType]` from an API. How can I convert `Future[MyType]` to `Future[Option[MyType]]`?

```
def getApiKey(id: String): Future[Option[MyType]] = Future {
  val g: Future[Option[MyType]] = getID(id) // error mismatch
  g
}

def getID(id: String): Future[MyType] = {
  //return Future[MyType]
}
```

Comment: tried but API return Future[MyType]  type but the required type is Future[Option[MyType]] thats why have convert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `map`:

```
def getApiKey(id: String): Future[Option[MyType]] = {
  getID(id).map(Option(_))
}
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks. I'm writing a little server app get data from API send back to the client. But getting nil data in GET request query successfully generated. Is there issue with Future? Should i set SleepTime?